# Why can't I read this scientific notation into GMP mpf_t?

Tags: gmp

I installed the libgmp3-dev package on Ubuntu 18.04 and am learning a bit how to use it. I wrote the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main()
{
    mpf_t x;
    mpf_t y;

    mpf_init(x);
    mpf_init(y);

    mpf_set_str(x, "9.95697589e-06", 10);
    mpf_set_str(y, "+9.95697589e-06", 10);

    printf("x: ");
    mpf_out_str(stdout, 10, 12, x);
    printf("\n");

    printf("y: ");
    mpf_out_str(stdout, 10, 12, y);
    printf("\n");

    mpf_clear(x);
    mpf_clear(y);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output looks like

```
x: 0.995697589e-5
y: 0.e0
```

I find it odd that a call like `sscanf("+9.0e-5", "%lf", &my_double);` handles this kind of format just fine, but mpf_set_str doesn't.

Why is 'y' showing up as 0?

Answer (score 0):

I found why - the code just doesn't handle them.

I downloaded the 6.1.2 release tarball and looked at the file `mpf/set_str.c`.

It needs the following fix to work with `+` characters at the beginning of the string.

```
negative = 0;
  if (c == '-')
    {
      negative = 1;
      c = (unsigned char) *++str;
    }

  /* add this */
  else if (c == '+')
    {
      c = (unsigned char) *++str;
    }
```

and then it worked for me.